Non int type 'list' issue in TabPy - Tableau & Python Integration
I am getting an error while calculating a multiplication through TabPy.
The error is shown below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dumbp4eArm-8jGX1tkOHqduzmjMHS-Fe/view?usp=sharing
An error occurred while communicating with the Analytics Extension data source 'Analytics Extension'

Error Code: 6116DD27
An error occurred while communicating with the Analytics Extension.
Error processing script
TypeError: Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

However, I am not multiplying list variables.



What do rejwt and qty look like? cos by the error message it looks like you're multiplying a sequence by another sequence and that's what the error is. you can replicate an iterable by multiplying it with an int and only an int. everything else fails
edit: fixed markdown and typos

I am unable to understand how Tableau is taking those 2 arguments as iterable because I am aggregating those 2 variables in the end. Can you please give an example how the calculation should be done?

I can't without knowing the 2 variables. that's why I asked cos it seems that both variables are iterable (probably both lists)

I have attached a link to the .twbx file in the post. Please let me know if it helps for better clarification. Thank you.
